# React Enzyme find second (or nth) node

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, enzyme

I'm testing a React component with Jasmine Enzyme shallow rendering.

Simplified here for the purposes of this question...

```
function MyOuterComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <MyInnerComponent title="Hello" />
      ...
      <MyInnerComponent title="Good-bye" />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

`MyOuterComponent` has 2 instances of `MyInnerComponent` and I'd like to test the props on each one.

The first one I know how to test.  I use `find` with `first`...

```
expect(component.find('MyInnerComponent').first()).toHaveProp('title', 'Hello');
```

However, I'm struggling to test the second instance of `MyInnerComponent`.

I was hoping something like this would work...

```
expect(component.find('MyInnerComponent').second()).toHaveProp('title', 'Good-bye');
```

or even this...

```
expect(component.find('MyInnerComponent')[1]).toHaveProp('title', 'Good-bye');
```

But of course neither of the above work.

I feel like I'm missing the obvious.

But when I look through the [docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) I don't see an analogous example.

Anyone?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

What you want is the `.at(index)` method: [.at(index)](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/at.html) .

So, for your example:

`expect(component.find('MyInnerComponent').at(1)).toHaveProp('title', 'Good-bye');`

Comment: for me it the `at()` worked using with `findAll()`, probably related to the version of the project.

Comment: .at(index) worked for me! Remember that all indexes start with 0.

Answer (score 16):

If you are to test certain things ***on each one*** also consider iterating through the matched set:

```
component.find('MyInnerComponent').forEach( (node) => {
    expect(node.prop('title')).toEqual('Good-bye')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 const component = wrapper.find('MyInnerComponent').at(1); 
 //at(1) index of element 0 to ~

 expect(component.prop('title')).to.equal('Good-bye');
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR;

use **findAll** along with **.at(1)**

```
const innerComponent = component.findAll('MyInnerComponent').at(1);
expect(innerComponent).toHaveProp('title', 'Good-bye');
```